# Watching the ThermalState of iPhone and notify the user

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm not very familiar with iOS development and I've a question for an use case that I want to implement and would like to get your feedback or input regarding the feasibility of the idea.

I basically want to use/watch all the time the [ThermalState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/thermalstate) of an iPhone XR and want to notify via audio signals or notification or any other visuell signal if the State of the device is `serious` or `critical`. This App should run all the time.

- Is this use case possible to implement also regarding passing the approval of AppStore?
- Could I run an application that is started automatically after a reboot of a iPhone (kind of a system app)?
- Are there any better API to look for the state of an ios/iphone device in particular for battery state?

Background: I need to notify the user (engineer in a manufacture industry) when his iPhone is getting too hot (particular: battery) in special area where he isn't allowed to enter.

Comment: What do you mean by "special area where he isn't allowed to enter"?

Comment: for e.g. gas industry where the atmosphere is explosiv and getting into this area should be observed. Does this help?

Comment: So you're saying that if your phone is slightly hot there's a chance the building could explode? - In this case, you cannot make an app for the app store to detect that. You should instead ban phones in that area.

Comment: But is it possible technically to run an app (background app) that observes the TermalState and signals the user somehow (audio/visuell)? Without launching the app explicitly?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by  "technically": Could I as a programmer do this? Yes, I could. Can you do and sell it through the App Store? - Pretty sure the answer is a definitive no.

Comment: what do you mean with "sell"? I want to have it for free on App Store so the special user who I want advise to download this App should download it from the official App Store.

Comment: In terms of the App Store "sell" applies to both free and paid apps. Is this really for just one single individual? - If so, why bother with the App Store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122808/discussion-between-imalik8088-and-jksoegaard).

Answer (score 1):

This app does not seem to fit in any of the categories deemed okay to run in the background at all times. Getting it into the App Store would be quite difficult, I imagine.

I also do not see why any user would want this program. You have included no justification for it in the question. Basically, if the thermal state is critical, iOS already has existing functionality to warn the user directly letting him know the device needs to cool off, so you wouldn't need a third party app to do the same thing.

Comment: thx for you input. I've amended my question with the background. The App is not for normal users. It should prevent or notify the user before entering a special area